# Rails 5 - nested controllers with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, nested-routes

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 5.

In order to keep the file structure neat, I'm trying to make folders inside my controllers directory, that I can use to group similar resources.

For example, I have:

```
 app/controllers/users/users_controller.rb
```

I can then make my sessions controller nested inside the controllers/users director so that all resources relating to the user are grouped under the user folder.

I'm stuck though for what to do with my routes file.

When I rake routes, I can see:

```
 users#index {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                                 POST     /users(.:format)                        users#create {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                        new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                    users#new {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                       edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                            user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                                 PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                                 PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
                                 DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy {:controllers=>{:users=>"users/users"}}
```

In my routes file, I've tried a few things (set out below) - none of them work:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
             :controllers => {
                :sessions => 'users/sessions',
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
              }

  resources :identities, 
    :controllers => {
        :identities => 'users/identities'
    }


  resources :users do
  scope module: :users do
    resources :users
    end
    end 

  root 'home#index'

end
```

I have also tried:

```
resources :users,
    :controllers => {
        :users => 'users/users'
    }
```

Each time, I get an error that says:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /users
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

I don't know what I need to do to get this working. I have changed each of my controllers that is nested inside the controllers/users folder with a prefix of:

```
 Users::
```

Can anyone see how to set this up so that I can keep my files neatly organised?

Note: I haven't created the same file directory structure in my models folder. I want to - but I'm concerned that I'm not able to figure this out for the controllers. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend you put the actual `users_controller` in the base controllers directory, and only put the nested controllers inside the `users` directory (ie follow the same structure as the nesting).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you put the actual `users_controller` in the base controllers directory, and only put the nested controllers inside the `users` directory (ie follow the same structure as the nesting).

The alternative is to name the `users_controller` the way that rails is expecting ie inside the `Users` module:

```
module Users
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
     ...
```

and then refer to it with: `Users::UsersController`
I always find the duplication in the name a bit cumbersome, and prefer top-level controllers to just be in the base directory.

Answer (score 4):

I also really like the approach explained in this video:

https://youtu.be/1B0Vioz4Ukw

Basically he creates `BaseController` for each Module, those inherit from `ApplicationController` and then the related controllers inherit directly from their corresponding `BaseController`.

### Example used in video

#### Controllers

Controllers are namespaced, in the example with Auth. Then a base class is made, derived from `ApplicationController`. The base class is then used for all other of the `Auth` controllers.

```
# app/controllers/auth/base_controller.rb
class Auth::BaseController < ApplicationController
end

# app/controllers/auth/posts_controller.rb
class Auth::PostsController < Auth::BaseController
  ...
end

# app/controllers/auth/sessions_controller.rb
class Auth::SessionsController < Auth::BaseController
  ...
end

# app/controllers/auth/users_controller.rb
class Auth::UsersController < Auth::BaseController
  ...
end
```

#### Routes

Resources are namespaced while simple routes have `auth/` added to their routes.

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :auth do
  resource :confirmation
  resource :session, only: [:create]
  resources :users, only: [:create]
end

get 'login' => 'auth/sessions/new'
delete 'logout' => 'auth/sessions#destroy'
get 'register' => 'auth/users#new'
```

#### Views

Views are now namespaced under auth.

```
app/views/auth/sessions/*
app/views/auth/posts/*
app/views/auth/users/*
```

#### Paths

Paths will also be under auth namespace to work. Check `rails routes` for details.

Example route: `auth_session_path`
Example route from set of objects: `[:auth, @user]`